# Looping until it find the word "year's" , Not working even there is a word "year's"

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have written a do until code in Word VBA to find the position of word "year's "

```
i = 1
Do
  i = i + 1
Loop Until UCase(wordobj.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(k).range.Words(i)) = "YEAR'S "
```

Here, in my document there is a word "year's " but loop is not ending and it running til the last word of the paragraph.

Comment: I have analysed some of your questions. You could get much more precise answer if only you ask more precise questions. It would be better if you tell us more about your needs, what you want to achieve. E.g. there are some possible ways to find `year's` in the document, less or more efficient, but it's important what for you search and what will be next step in your code. Even solution from Tomalak works it's not efficient one. If you need some more help please elaborate on your needs.

Comment: @KazJaw I need to find the position of the word "year's" in the specific paragraph, so that i can find the word which appears before of after the word "year's" ..

Comment: Does Tomalak answer work for you as expected?

Comment: @ kazjaw No i didn't try the Tomalak Code, As i dont know how to type this character `"’"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Word automatically translates plain apostrophes into typographical ones.

So `year's` becomes `year’s` and your comparison fails.

```
Sub test()
  Dim p As Paragraph, w As Range
  Dim i As Integer, t As String, found As Boolean

  For Each p In wordobj.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    For Each w In p.Range.Words
      t = Replace(Trim(UCase(w)), "’", "'")
      i = i + 1
      If t = "YEAR'S" Then
        found = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next w
    If found Then Debug.Print "Found at " & i
  Next p
End Sub
```

On a related note I strongly dis-recommend the use of potentially infinite loops like `Do .. Loop` or `While .. Wend` in such a situation.

Use `For Each .. Next`, that's more convenient and cannot run into an overflow.